# Joining 5 .rpt files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, left-join

I am new to data science and working on my 1st project. I have 5 files with around 6GB of data and I am doing left outer join on the data an I see around 1680 GB of data is getting generated.

I guess something is wrong with my joins and pandas.

````
    ```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.read_table("a.rpt")
b = pd.read_table("b.rpt")
c = pd.read_table("c.rpt")
d = pd.read_table("d.rpt")
e = pd.read_table("e.rpt")
import os
folderPath = r'/Users/sahithi/Desktop/data'
if not os.path.exists(folderPath):
  os.makedirs(folderPath)
uniqueIds=b.WEIGHT.unique()
for id in uniqueIds:
Record = b.loc[dx['WEIGHT'] == id]
path = folderPath+"/"+str(id)+".csv"
Record.to_csv(path)
mc = pd.merge(Record, c, on = 'NAME', how='left')
ma = pd.merge(mc, a, on = 'NAME', how='left')
md = pd.merge(ma, d, on = 'NAME', how='left')
me = pd.merge(md, e, on = 'NAME', how='left')
me.to_csv(path)
    ```
````

Comment: There could be duplicate rows on `NAME` across files which could lead to increase in size after join.